# files disappearing after pushing to local branch and remote

Tags: git, github

In my Git repo, I have 3 branches:

- master
- dev
- gh-pages

My primary idea is to commit all data to `dev, gh-pages` (and to push to remote for storing or backing up). After all is done.. merge to master.

What's interesting is.. when I commit data to dev, `gh-pages` and push them, my files are disappearing! (why its happening?)

Now, after all happened, I want to clone my repo, work on it again.. as there are no files on master, its cloning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used `git merge master` while in either `dev` or `gh-pages`, this merges **from** `master`, not **to** `master`.

You need to first switch to master, then merge from the branch you want to merge from:

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch>
```

By the way, `gh-pages` should be separate from your code. It's for the documentation of a github repository, and those files have nothing to do with your code. Don't merge its content into `master`.

Comment: hey.. I am damn new to Git but this is what happening! when I do `git checkout dev` I see my files, they are going away as soon as I do `git checkout master`.. what's that

Comment: Try gitk --all to get a visual indication where your commits have ended up.

Comment: As I said, `merge` merges *from* the named branch *to* the current branch.

Comment: Firstly, it is correct to work in a Dev branch directly, not master. Secondly, Femaref is correct, 1) git checkout master 2) git merge dev